# Select rows based on value in specific column

Tags: r, awk

I have a file like the one below. I would like to print the rows for which the value in the last column is higher than 90. I am not sure how to specify the correct column.

```
29974   A1CF    NM_138932       9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  99
29974   A1CF    NM_138933       9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  99
29974   A1CF    NM_014576       9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  99
29974   A1CF    NM_001198820    9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  69
29974   A1CF    NM_001198819    9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  89
29974   A1CF    NM_001198818    9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(df[which(df[,ncol(df)]>90),])
```

In wich df is the name of your dataframe object.

Comment: What if the last column has the columnname: V15

Comment: as long as it is the last column the statement above will work , since df[,ncol(df)] defines the last column in your dataframe. If you want to use the name of your column , there are several options:  print(df[which(df$V15>90),])
print(df[which(df[,"V15"]>90),])

Comment: target90 <- print(target[which(target[,ncol(target)]>90),])
 [1] V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(target[, ncol(target)], 90) : '>' not meaningful for factors

Comment: you should make your last column numeric for this to work... that is what the error message is telling you.... your last column is a factor. change it like this target[,ncol(target)]<-as.numeric(target[,ncol(target)])

Comment: @jebsel your `which`s are all unnecessary.

Comment: yes you are right, thanks for the remark, I have used them in the past and always keep forgetten they are not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Through awk.

```
$ awk '$NF>90' file
29974   A1CF    NM_138932       9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  99
29974   A1CF    NM_138933       9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  99
29974   A1CF    NM_014576       9606    hsa-miR-4711-3p 3       25      32      -0.018  -0.095  -0.108  0.003   0.017   -0.448  99
```

Awk process the input file, record by record ie, row by row.
`NF` is a special variable in awk which stores the last column number. So `$NF` contains the value of last column. So  `$NF>90` will check for the value of last column is greater than 90 or not. If it's true then awk prints the corresponding row.